# Clarification about the JavaScript for..in notation

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

Is x here a number? It is used like that in the `person[x]` part below. How does this work, I'm so lost on it:

```
var person={fname:"John",lname:"Doe",age:25}; 
var x;

for (x in person)
{
document.write(person[x] + " ");
}
```

I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: think of it as `for (key in object)`, within the loop you'd use `value = object[key]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `x` is not a number. That would only be the case if you were iterating over an `Array`, in which case `x` would be the numeric index of the element. In this case, it would be a string since JavaScript objects are really Associative Arrays (indexed by strings). It would be the name of each one of the fields in the object:

```
for (var x in person) {
    document.write(x + ' = ' + person[x]);
}
```

Should output:

```
fname = John
lname = Doe
age = 25
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Justin! And I will read more about Associative Arrays.

Comment: In case of arrays, `x` would be a string as well. As object's property name is always a string.

Comment: @katspaugh - In that case, x would only be a string only if the user added additional properties to the array. Otherwise the for...in loop would only iterate over the array indexes...which are not strings.

Comment: Justin Niessner, keys are *always* strings. When you access array elements via their numeric indeces, they are implicitly (hence the confusion) converted to strings. `for (var i in [0]) { console.log(typeof i); } // string`

Answer (score 2):

Forget about `for (key in obj)`. Citing one prominent educator here:

> Everyone knows you should iterate over the keys of an object, not the object itself.

Thus, the right way to iterate over objects is:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj); // array of keys 

for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    var item = obj[keys[i]];
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For...in iterates over enumerable properties of an object. I'd suggest reading through the [MDN page on for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for more detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

Adel you have to understand the basic data structure.

`

1> In above code snippet "person" is not an array it is a dictionary or hash tables(thats why x is not number).They are array of key:value pairs.See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

2>"Dictionaries/Associative arrays" are iterated over keys.
so the code `for(x in person)` will give you array of keys and not number witch we expect in array iteration.try `for(x in person){console.log(x);}`